# RegEx Replace that adds brackets around phrases

Tags: c#, regex

I need a RegEx that will add brackets to a string of words when a comma is encountered. An example may be easier:

> I was here,there --> (I was here),there
>
> Bob,here thee there,somewhere --> Bob,(here thee there),somewhere
>
> Sue,Bob,Joe,here thee here --> Sue,Bob,Joe,(here thee here)
>
> Milly Barry Molly,Joe Sandy Mary --> (Milly Barry Molly),(Joe Sandy Mary)

Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried _anything_?

Comment: Given your text examples: `I was here,there` and `Milly and Molly,Joe and Mary` you want different results for what is essentially the same input.

Comment: So the rule is that, between commas, brackets are added if there are multiple sequences of word characters separated by at least one space?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: From what I understand, `and` seems also to be part of solving the problem.

Comment: @npinti - last I checked, `was` wasn't `and`.

Comment: @SonerGönül, I'm just looking for a start.

Comment: @npinti, no they are different. Damien_The_Unbeliever has the right interpretation. Ignore the "and" it could be any word

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I updated the question. Basically the "spaced" words need to be grouped (by brackets) if the sentence contains a comma. Words only separated by comma dont need to be grouped by bracket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
string input = "Milly Barry Molly,Joe Sandy Mary";

Regex regex = new Regex(
    @"(?<=^|,)\s*(?>[^\s,]+\s*){2,}(?=,)|(?<=,)\s*(?>[^\s,]+\s*){2,}$" );
string result = regex.Replace(input, "($&)");

Console.WriteLine(result);
// (Milly Barry Molly),(Joe Sandy Mary)
```

Further explanation on request.

Comment: Mate, really appreciate this. I rarely ask questions on SO and even more rare asking question without any sample code. Your solution works a treat.

Comment: @ozczecho. I had to edit the solution as previously if a sentence did not contain any `,` it would still be enclosed in `()`. Unfortunately this has made the regex quite a lot longer.

Comment: @MikeM- it passed all my unit tests :-) ... I just added a new one.... thanks again.